# Working with routes and Entrust in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to work with Entrust ACL in my application running on Laravel 5.2. I've installed the package following the instruction on GitHub page of Entrust and everything went well.

I've added this route group in my routes.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Backend', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('roles',['as'=>'roles','uses'=>'RoleController@index','middleware' => ['permission:role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete']])->name('admin.roles');
    Route::get('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.create','uses'=>'RoleController@create','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']])->name('admin.roles.create');
    Route::post('roles/create',['as'=>'roles.store','uses'=>'RoleController@store','middleware' => ['permission:role-create']])->name('admin.roles.create');
});
```

This is my RoleController

```
class RoleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $roles = Role::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
        return view('backend.roles.index',compact('roles'))->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $permission = Permission::get();
        return view('backend.roles.create',compact('permission'));
    }
}
```

view files are in `resources/views/backend/roles/`. I believe something is wrong with the routes but can't understand what.

When I try to open `http://localhost/admin/roles` I've got this error:

> HttpException in Application.php line 905:
>
> in Application.php line 905
>
> at Application->abort('403', '', array()) in helpers.php line 30
>   at abort('403') in EntrustPermission.php line 39
>
> at EntrustPermission->handle(object(Request), object(Closure), 'role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete')
>
> at call_user_func_array(array(object(EntrustPermission), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure), 'role-list|role-create|role-edit|role-delete')) in Pipeline.php line 136

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Now I've got `Route [roles.create] not defined.` in my view here:

```
@permission('role-create')
   <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('roles.create') }}"> Create New Role</a>
@endpermission
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U have to attach role_id and user_id first and middleware should be like

```
  'middleware' => ['auth','admin']
```

Comment: If I change middleware to my existing role `role:superadmin` I've got `Missing argument 3 for Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::handle()` error

Comment: 'role' => 'Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole',
'permission' => 'Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission',
'ability' => 'Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility',add above lines in kernal.php to route routeMiddleware

Comment: I've added them while I installed the package

Comment: I've updated my question with the error from the view this time. The route and controller are above too

Comment: There is no route called roles.create in your route.php